# How to reduce list to map with Java functional API

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I want to transform a string of text to a dictionary, which contains all the *unique* words as a key, and translation as a value.

I know how to transform a String into a *stream* containing unique words `(Split -> List -> stream() -> distinct())`, and I have translation service available, but what is the most convenient way to reduce the stream into `Map` with the original element and it's translation in general?

Comment: I think you're looking for [Collectors.toMap(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: Could you please post your code? What you tried to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can directly do that via collect:

```
yourDistinctStringStream
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Function.identity(), yourTranslatorService::translate
);
```

This returns a `Map<String, String>` where the map key is the original string and the map value would be the translation.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have a list of strings `"word1", "word2", "wordN"` with no repetitions:

This should solve the the problem

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("word1", "word2", "workdN");
    
Map<String, String> collect = list.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> translationService(s)));
```

This will return, the insertion order is not maintained.

> {wordN=translationN, word2=translation2, word1=translation1}

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "hello world java stream stream";

    Map<String, String> result = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(text.split(" "))).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(word -> word, word -> translate(word)));

    System.out.println(result);
}

private static String translate(String word) {
    return "T-" + word;
}
```

Will give you output:

> {java=T-java, world=T-world, stream=T-stream, hello=T-hello}